# Command to Activate New Data Screen linked to Current Screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a List-And-Details screen with a button in the details section.  When I click on the button, I want to navigate to a New Data Screen to create an order but have that order tied to the customer displayed in the details screen where the button was clicked.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you have two screens: a Customer List screen, and a New Order screen. What I would suggest are the following steps:

1. Create a customerId property on the New Order screen
2. Mark the customerId property as a screen parameter
3. When you click the button and navigate to the New Order screen
   (ShowNewOrderScreen), pass the id of the selected Customer
4. On the created event of the New Order screen, process the customerId
   property.
5. You can load the customer object, then instantiate and add a new
   order to it.

Comment: That's the direction I was thinking Bryan, but could you give me some more detail on step #3?  I'm on day #2 of using Lightswitch and the tutorials I have found so far do not address this use.

Comment: Click on CustomerID (on the left-hand side of the screen), then in the Properties Panel (usually on the right-hand side of the screen) you'll see a "IsParameter" checkbox. Tick that.

Comment: On step #3, you update the execute code of the button you have mentioned. Your code would look something like this: Application.ShowNewDataScreen(Customers.SelectedItem.Id)